# Binomial theorem question ($a$, $b$, $c$ s.t. $m^3=a{m\choose3}+b{m\choose 2}+c{m\choose 1}\forall m$)

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

> Find integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ such that $$m^3=a{m\choose3}+b{m\choose 2}+c{m\choose 1}$$ $\forall$ $m$. Then sum the series
> $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3.$$

> First, we solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$. Both sides of the equation are polynomials of degree 3. By considering the coefficient of $m^3$ on both sides, we obtain $a=6$. Evaluating both sides at $m=1$ we obtain $c=1$, and then evaluating both sides at $m=2$ we obtain $b=6$.

Where exactly do $a=6$, $b=6$, and $c=1$ come from?

Comment: The answer is contained in the question. But when it says "by considering", you should actually stop and consider that, and "evaluating" means you should actually go and evaluate. You do need to know that $\binom mk=\frac{m(m-1)\cdots,(m-k+1)}{k!}$ and do some trivial manipulation of equations to reduce them to $a=6$ and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m^3=a {m \choose 3} +b {m \choose 2}+ c{m \choose 1} = a\frac{m(m-1)(m-2)}{6}+b \frac{m(m-1)}{2} +c m.$$
$$m^3=a \frac{m^3-3m^2+2m}{6}+b\frac{m^2-m}{2}+cm=\frac{a}{3}m^3+(\frac{a}{2}-\frac{b}{2}) m^2+(\frac{a}{3}-\frac{b}{2}+c) m.$$ On comparinc thge coefficients of powers of $m$, we get $a=6, a-b=0, a/3-b/2+c=0$, then $a=6=b, c=1$, 
Fyrther, we use $$\sum_{k=1}^{m} {k \choose j} ={n+1 \choose j+1}.$$ to get
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{n} m^3 = \sum_{m=1}^n \left [6 {m \choose 3} +6 {m \choose 2} + 1 {m \choose 1} \right] = 6 {n+1 \choose 4} + 6 {n+1 \choose 3} + {n+1 \choose 2}$$
$$\implies S=\frac{1}{4} (n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)+(n+1)n(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}(n+1)n]=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Expanding and collecting like terms we get
$$m^2(a-6)+m(-3a-3b)+2a+3b+6c=0$$